# How to split parts of an equation over two lines?

Tags: equations

I have a question concerning equations in Latex. Let's assume there is a simple piecewise function as below (the actual one has terms which are much longer):

[image]

As each line runs on for quite a bit, I would like to split the selector over two lines however still aligned with the case. Is this possible?

```
\begin{equation}
    \label{eqn:c(n)}
    {
        c(n) = \begin{cases}
            f(x)), & $if n=0 where x=1$ \\[1em]
            f(x), & $if n\textgreater0 where x=c(n-1)+n$ \\
        \end{cases}
    }
\end{equation}
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you employ a `cases` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package) and embed in it two `array` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'cases' environment
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for '\addlinespace' macro

\begin{document}
\[
C(n)=
\begin{cases}
f(x), & \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
          n=0\\
          \text{where $x=1$} 
        \end{array} \\ \addlinespace % increase the vertical separation
f(x), & \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
          n>0\\
          \text{where $x=c(n-1)+n$}
        \end{array}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two approaches to this. I'll use the `amsmath` `cases` environment to simplify things, but this would work just as well if you were building things up manually with `array` on your own.

**Option 1** (less typing), use an empty cell in the left column (see lines marked ❶_ to make things line up:

```
\[
C(n)=
\begin{cases}
f(x), &n=0\\
      &\textrm{where $x=1$}\\ % ❶
f(x), &n>0\\
      &\textrm{where $x=c(n-1)+n % ❶
\end{cases}
\]
```

Note that I opted for `\textrm` rather than `\text` as the latter will inherit the formatting of the surrounding text which can lead to unexpected results in, e.g., the text of a theorem.

**Option 2** (perhaps better aesthetics).

First, we'll define a command `\stackmath` to build up a single-column array.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\stackmath}{m}
   {
     \begin{array}{@{} l @{}} % ❷
       #1
     \end{array}
   }
```

Note that we put `@{}` at the sides of the array ❷ to avoid the extra spacing LaTeX puts there by default. This is a generally useful command in that it will let us typeset left-justified math in multiple lines anywhere in math mode by typing something like:

```
\stackmath{x<0\\x>0}
```

to get the lines stacked up.

Then we can write

```
\[
C(n)=
\begin{cases}
f(x), &\stackmath{n=0\\
       \textrm{where $x=1$}}\\ % ❸
f(x), &\stackmath{n>0\\
      \textrm{where $x=c(n-1)+n}
\end{cases}
\]
```

You may find yourself wanting to use the optional argument on `\\` at ❸ to open things up a bit, writing, e.g., `\\[5pt]` to get some extra space between lines in the `cases` environment.